# Create a chart inside a component/view?

Tags: react-sketchapp

Im wondering if anyone knows how to create a chart (with fake data to use as a symbol) with this tool.

maybe a starting point would be something like:

```
class Chart extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        new highcharts.Chart({
          renderTo: 'myChartExample', 
          type: column
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <View name="myChartExample"></View>;
    }
}
```

A developer helped me with the above code as a starting point. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of an easy, high-level way to do it currently.

We have a [ticket open](https://github.com/airbnb/react-sketchapp/issues/16) for adding in SVG support — if we do that then an SVG charting library should work.